# Autowidth Box for Itemize Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, block, varwidth

A newenvironment is defined using varwidth and tikz to get a block of width equal to that of the content within it. It works fine, unless itemization is involved. A MWE is given here.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\tikzstyle{example-box} = [fill=yellow, rectangle]

\newenvironment{autowidthblock}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [example-box] (box)
\bgroup 
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}

}{
\end{varwidth}
\egroup;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{autowidthblock}
With normal sentences, the width is rightly fit
\end{autowidthblock}

\begin{autowidthblock}
\begin{itemize}
\item With itemize environment,
\item The width is not auto-set
\item Instead spans the entire textwidth
\end{itemize}
\end{autowidthblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Can anybody suggest a way to make the width auto for itemization/enumeration as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are dealing with two very different things here: 1) In the case that works as you want, the material can be typeset in an `\hbox` (or in `\mbox`, if you prefer, i.e.: in LR-mode). There can't be any automatic line wrapping. 2) List environments such as `itemize`, on the other hand, can only be used in vertical mode; they always require an `\hsize` which determines where automatic line wrapping happens. In your case, the `itemize` environment is inside a `\vbox` of width `\linewidth`. With more text, you would see the line wrapping. If you want automatic line wrapping, ... (continued)

Comment: you need to specify a width, and this will be the width of your box (though you can make it bigger by adding space, etc.). On the other hand, if you *don't* need any automatic line wrapping in the list environment, then I think that `itemize` is the wrong tool. Implementing your list as a `tabular` containing a single column of type `l` would allow the automatic width determination that you appear to want. With the `array` package, you can use the `>{...}` syntax to automatically insert the “bullets” and the horizontal skip (space) following them.

Comment: Did the above comments help solve your problem ?

Comment: @BambOo, No, I thought the only way is to wrap it in a minipage and specify width manually.

Comment: If you found a solution, please answer your own question so that other users may benefit from your experience